# Puppet to only create virtualenv once

Tags: python, virtualenv, puppet

I am using this class in my manifest:

```
python::virtualenv { $virtualenv_dir:
ensure => present,
version => 'system',
systempkgs => false,
distribute => false,
owner => $user,
group => $group,
}
```

It works great the first time.

The problem is I have several daemonized celery workers launched which are using the venv/bin/python file.

When I apply the manifest second time, I get:

```
Already using interpreter /usr/bin/python
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/virtualenv", line 3, in 
virtualenv.main()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 938, in main
never_download=options.never_download)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1039, in create_environment
site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1274, in install_python
shutil.copyfile(executable, py_executable)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile
with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 26] Text file busy: '/usr/local/myapp/venv/bin/python'
```

Is it somehow possible to only run virtualenv command if the venv directory has not been created yet?

Or what would you suggest? I don't want to stop my celery workers while applying the puppet manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to run the command of an `exec` resource only when a particular file isn't created yet, by using the `creates` parameter:

```
exec { 'mycommand':
    command => '/usr/bin/something a b c',
    creates => '/var/lib/xxx';
}
```

This will run the command only when `/var/lib/xxx` doesn't exist.